# How To Customize CellStyle For DataGrid Columns And Rows

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid

So i have a calendar and a button. After i select the date and click the button, the program is supposed to get the data from the selected date from a sql database. I collect that data in a datatable, and i want to show this datatable in the datagrid. Here's my behind code:

```
Private Sub btnFiltro_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnFiltro.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = b.fillDataGrid(from.SelectedDate)
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView

End Sub

Public Function fillDataGrid(ByVal Data As Date) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT [Statusi] FROM [Database1].[dbo].[Table1] WHERE Data = @Data", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", Data)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    adp.Fill(dt)
    Return dt
End Function
```

This is how i display data on my datagrid. What i want to do now, is that i want to change the foreground color to red of rows where the value of cell under the Status column is equal to "Humbese". And i tried to do that like this:

```
<DataGrid attributes here... >
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}"  Value="Humbese" >
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

But this does what i want only if i manually write "Humbese" in that particular cell. What i want is, to change the color automatically, in other words when i click the button i want the foreground color of the row to already be red, if its cell contains the string "Humbese".
Do you have any idea how to do that?

EDIT 1:
I created a new project to try your code and here's my full code:
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:datagridExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="385.993" Width="739.716">
<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}"  Value="Humbese" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <!--
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
          CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle1}" />

-->

    <DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Ora}"
                            Width="*"
                            Header="Date"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Status}" 
                            CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle1}"
                            Width="*"
                            Header="Status" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>


    <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click">LOAD</Button>
    <Calendar x:Name="from" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="253,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.vb :

```
Class MainWindow

Dim vm As Class1
Sub New()


    InitializeComponent()
    vm = New Class1()

    DataContext = vm

End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    vm.LoadData(from.SelectedDate())
End Sub
End Class
```

Class1.vb (your viewmodel class):

```
Public Class Class1
Public Property Data() As MyDataTable
    Get
        Return m_Data
    End Get
    Set
        m_Data = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_Data As MyDataTable

Public Sub New()
    Data = New MyDataTable()
End Sub

Public Sub LoadData(dataaa As Date)
    Data.loadData(dataaa)
End Sub
End Class
```

MyDataTable.vb :

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class MyDataTable
Inherits DataTable
Dim conn As SqlConnection
Dim stringBuilder As SqlConnectionStringBuilder
Dim statusi As Integer()

Sub New()
    connectTo()
    Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
    Columns.Add("Statusi", GetType(String))
End Sub

Public Sub connectTo()
    stringBuilder = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
    stringBuilder.DataSource = "DESKTOP-CPTM4LG\SQLEXPRESS"
    stringBuilder.InitialCatalog = "database1"
    stringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = True

    conn = New SqlConnection(stringBuilder.ToString())
End Sub

Public Sub loadData(data As Date)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT [Ora], [Status] FROM [database1].[dbo].[table1] WHERE Data = @Data", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", data)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    adp.Fill(Me)


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: The entire row or just the cell ?

Comment: The entire row. I know that TargetType is DataGridCell but for some reason it changes the color of the entire row when i manually write "Humbese" in that particular cell.

Comment: Please you have the code along with button. that will hep in answering more specifically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the cell style for a specific column, apply your style to that particular column:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date}"
                                Width="*"
                                Header="Date"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Status}" 
                                CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle1}"
                                Width="*"
                                Header="Status" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

[image]

In order to change the cell style for all columns in a specific row, apply the style to the `DataGrid`:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
              CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle1}" />
```

[image]

**Style:**

```
    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}"  Value="Humbese" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

---

**EDIT:** Adding full-code:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication313.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication313"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="300" 
    Width="300">
<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}"  Value="Humbese" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <!--
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
              CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle1}" />

    -->

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date}"
                                Width="*"
                                Header="Date"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Status}" 
                                CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle1}"
                                Width="*"
                                Header="Status" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>


    <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click">LOAD</Button>

</Grid>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MyViewModel vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vm = new MyViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.LoadData();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyDataTable Data { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Data = new MyDataTable();
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        // loading data from DB here
        Data.LoadData();
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:** It shouldn't matter, but adding code for filling the `DataTable`, to make it even more clear.

```
public class MyDataTable : DataTable
{
    public MyDataTable()
    {
        Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        // for simplicity, please assume data loaded from DB here

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = NewRow();
            dr["Date"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i).Date;
            dr["Status"] = string.Format("Status {0}", i);
            Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        Rows[2]["Status"] = "Humbese";
        Rows[4]["Status"] = "Humbese";
        Rows[7]["Status"] = "Humbese";
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 3:** The problem with your code is an inconsistency in the column name: the `DataTable` declares it as `Statusi` and the binding uses `Status`. Your code worked after I fixed that:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This looks great, but it is not working for me. I must've made some mistake and i really am a very beginner in xaml. So i put the Style tag into windows resources, and i don't know if this is the right thing to do. And i don't understand, what parameters should i give in itemsource attribute.

Comment: This too works only if i manually write "Humbese" in that particular cell :/

Comment: I think i'm missing something in the itemsource property. What should i write instead of data here: itemsource = "{Binding data}". And still i don't understand why should i add this itemsource property if i set it when the button is clicked with: dataGrid.itemsource = dt.defaultView

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**, I just added **full code**.

Comment: But i need to see how you fill the datagrid, the new edit doesn't really make a difference. But anyway, many thanks

Comment: The datagrid does not get _"filled"_.... its `ItemsSource` is bound in XAML to a `DataTable` called `Data`.

Comment: Please see my **EDIT 2**. It shouldn't matter for our purposes here but hopefully it will make it more clear for you. Also I would suggest you to start a fresh sample project and use this code to verify it does actually work. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. It works when i write your code in the loadData sub of the MyDataTable class, but does not work when i fill the datatable with sqlAdapter like this: adp.fill(Me)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126534/discussion-between-eae-and-jstreet).

Comment: Please see my **EDIT 3**.

Comment: No still didn't work after that. But i found a solution:
For i as Integer to Me.Rows.Count
  If Rows(i)("Statusi").ToString.Contains("H") Then
                Rows(i)("Statusi") = "Humbese"
            End If
        Next
This does it. So thanks a lot!! :D

Comment: So practically i'm just rewriting it. If it is "Humbese" then make it "Humbese". And that works :/

Comment: Well, ok.... but that is not necessary at all... the correct thing to do is to make your column names consistent with your XAML. I changed your XAML from `Status` to `Statusi` in two places: the `Style` definition itself and also in the `DataGrid` column binding. If you keep overlooking details like that, nothing will ever work like it should. BTW, if you look at the `Output` window in VS you will see that was causing 10 binding exceptions, one for each row in the data grid. And that was how I found the problem.